# Kotlin: Is there a sugar grammar that casts to a boolean?

Tags: kotlin

in javascript

```js
!1 // false
!0 // true
!{foo: "bar"} // false
```

Kotlin is like a mixture of JavaScript, CoffeeScript, and Java.

I know that the following code runs in Kotlin:

```
!true // false
```

However, using `!` for numbers or strings or other class will cause a syntax error.

Is there another way? Or is there no way at all?

Comment: What **exactly** are you trying to achieve? Cast the result of an expression to a `Boolean`?

Comment: I want to determine if there is an arbitrary value and replace it with a boolean (like JavaScript's automatic casting).

Comment: Kotlin is very different from JavaScript.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `!` does not work on numbers but only on booleans and in conjunction with stuff like `!=`, `!in`. You cannot treat numbers as booleans in Kotlin and equally you don't check nullability or emptiness that way. Please don't believe it is based on JavaScript in any way. Most of Kotlin's type system is explicit, it doesn't allow shortcuts like JS and you will use things like `list.isNotEmpty()`, `if(list != null)` instead.

I think JavaScript is an example of a language you should not take as your role model.

Answer (score 1):

You simply can create a Kotlin [extension](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html)

Like:

```
val Int.bool:Boolean get() = this == 1 // 1 is true other values are false
```

Or

```
val Int.bool:Boolean get() = this != 0 // 0 is false other values are true

val intVal = 1
println (intVal.bool) // true
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want this, Kotlin does allow you to overload the `!` operator:

```
operator fun Any?.not() = when(this) {
    false, null, 0, 0.0, 0L, "" -> true
    else -> false
}
```

**This is a bad idea** for reasons already explained by @s1m0nw1's answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is a method [`String.toBoolean`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/to-boolean.html) in Kotlin, which just

> Returns `true` if the contents of this string is equal to the word `"true"`, ignoring case, and `false` otherwise.

Example:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val t: Boolean = "true".toBoolean()
    println(t)
    val f: Boolean = "false".toBoolean()
    println(f)
    val x: Boolean = "x".toBoolean()
    println(x)
}
```

Output:

```
true
false
false
```

There is no possibility like that for instances of other classes.